# Drag and Drop WPF ComboBox, Buttons, Radio Buttons, etc

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a problem, i've already read tutorials, blogs, etc about drag and drop on WPF (i'm using VS10).

The problem is I need to have a toolbox with buttons,combobox, radio button,etc sothe user can drag it and drop it(copy) on a work space (canvas or whatever).

I managed to do drag and drop from textbox and images but that doesn't work for me, when i tried on buttons or combobox it just doesnt work, i assume it is cause of the click event by default, i don't know what the problem is tho. Here is what i've tried with a button.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,36,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" Text="Drag" />
    <TextBox Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="225,136,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Text="Drop" />
    <Label Content="DragLabel" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,36,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" MouseDown="label1_MouseDown" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,122,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" MouseDown="button1_MouseDown" AllowDrop="True" IsEnabled="True" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Rectangle Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="149,199,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" AllowDrop="True" Fill="#FFDCA1A1" />
</Grid>
```

My Code Behind ...

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)sender;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbl, lbl.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }


        private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var dependencyObject = (Button)sender;
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dependencyObject, dependencyObject, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Thank You in advance guys. Btw sry about my english :s...

Thx again!

Luis

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `PreviewMouseDown` event instead of `MouseDown`? Your code will get called before the `Button` can capture the click.

WPF elements normally use [RoutedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) which often have a corresponding "Preview" event that uses the [Tunneling Routing Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies), which will be sent to all parents before the element that actually raised the event. This allows you to perform your operation in response to the `MouseDown` **before** the `Button` gets a chance to try to execute a click action.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var dependencyObject = (Button)sender;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(dependencyObject, dependencyObject, DragDropEffects.Move); 
}
```

will work as mentioned by **Abe**